# Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010 + MyEclipse 9.1 + TFS 2010 = Not Able To Connect to Multiple Projects

Tags: myeclipse, team-explorer-everywhere

I am having a problem where My Eclipse 9.1 is not able to connect to multiple projects in 2010 using the Team Explorer Everywhere plugin. If I try to connect a second project, it disconnects me from the first one. I can not find any way to be able to pull down multiple projects like I was in TFS 2008.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is as-designed.  Team Explorer Everywhere can only connect to a single Team Project Collection at a time.  There are myriad reasons why this is the case, but all are to preserve the notion of atomic operations against the server.  Some operations (for example, check-in) simply *must* be scoped to a single server instance in order to make sense.

Since a single changeset is atomic in TFS, an attempt to check-in multiple pending changes either *all succeed* or *all fail*.  Consider if you had pending changes from two different servers:  you cannot commit all these changes as a single changeset - one server could reject your check-in due to conflicts, while the other could proceed successfully.  This is, at best, confusing, but most likely actually leaves your projects in an inconsistent state since there may be dependencies between these projects.  Since there are distinct changesets for each server, the UI must reflect that.

After much deliberation and experimentation, we concluded that the best user experience is simply to have an experience where you can import projects from multiple TFS servers, but you must select which server you want to work with in the UI by selecting which one is currently "online".  All TFS functionality is available for the online server which a limited subset of the TFS functionality is available to the other projects.

We would recommend that you consolidate your Java projects to a single Team Project Collection if you need to import all of them.

This behavior is unchanged from any previous versions of the software, including before the acquisition of the technology by Microsoft (when the product was still part of Teamprise Client Suite.)

Also note that the scope of commands available to "offline" projects has increased dramatically in TFS 2012 thanks to the new Local Workspace functionality.

Comment: I think I just worded my question poorly.


The problem we are seeing is that we have multiple projects open in a single MyEclipse work-space. Something is causing the projects to become unconnectable, but a rebuilding the work-space fixes the problem (at least for the time being).

Comment: Oh, well, in that case ignore the above ramblings.  I suspect that there's some intermittent server connectivity problems - could you drop me an email (address is in my profile) and we can get to the bottom of it?